# Getting a list of all Media in Instagram with Graph API

Tags: instagram-graph-api

In my code, I have been pulling the list of media in Instagram using the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/media?fields=media_url,{..some fields here...}&limit=10000&access_token={my_access_token}
```

This was working fine and I didn't touch the code for a month. Now suddenly it gives the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (Application)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Aty4vnPpLWfGq9Hj6hQFtZR"
  }
}
```

Nothing in the documentation says that media is no longer available. Graph API version has updated from v14 to v15 since I used it, but the request isn't working on either version.

Access token is fine because other requests are working correctly.

Does anyone have any insights? What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are defining an invalid field. Below is a list of fields you can use. Also i suggest you also try **instagram account id** instead of **app_id**.

```
fields=[id,ig_id,media_product_type,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,timestamp,
username,like_count,comments_count]
```

final url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/media?fields=id,ig_id,media_product_type,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,timestamp,
username,like_count,comments_count&access_token={my_access_token}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (Application)". Also ig_id is an unknown field

Comment: did you find the instagram account id? because when i use something else instead of instagram account id i get the same error as you.

Comment: you are right! I was using Meta App Id instead of Instagram account Id. If you state it as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: Can you get the output you want ? is there still an error?

Comment: Yes I can get the needed output. Thanks!